# Python algorithm of counting occurrence of specific word in csv

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, counting

I've just started to learn python.
I'm curious about what are the efficient ways to count the occurrence of a specific word in a CSV file, other than simply use for loop to go through line by line and read.

To be more specific, let's say I have a CSV file contain two columns, "Name" and "Grade", with  millions of records.

How would one count the occurrence of "A" under "Grade"?

Python code samples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to read the whole file, otherwise your algorithm can be proven to be incorrect.  Reading it linearly, line by line, is not a bad approach.

Comment: `import csv;
    count = sum(1 for row in csv.dictreader(open(filename)) if row['Grade'] == 'A')`

Comment: @agf: nice, but when I tried this it was a factor of 6-8 slower than the other answers

Comment: @steabert That speed factor almost certainly doesn't matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basic example, with using [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) and [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#counter-objects) (Python 2.7+) from standard Python libraly:

```
import csv
import collections

grades = collections.Counter()
with open('file.csv') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=';'):
        grades[row[1]] += 1

print 'Number of A grades: %s' % grades['A']
print grades.most_common()
```

Output (for small dataset):

```
Number of A grades: 2055
[('A', 2055), ('B', 2034), ('D', 1995), ('E', 1977), ('C', 1939)]
```

Comment: OK, but you could apply `Counter` on a generator expression for the first element of the lines in the file

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer. But I was wondering comparing this with using dictionary, with grade as key and occurrence as value, which way will be more efficient?

Comment: @laotanzhurou, `Counter` is a `dict` subclass, but it's little slower. If you really need speedup [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or `if ... count += 1` probably will be faster. But you always can benchmark it by yourself with [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html), see _Johnsyweb's_ [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9247545/1052325)

Answer (score 3):

You should of course read all the grades, which in this case also means reading the entire file.  You can use the `csv` module to easily read comma separated value files:

```
import csv
my_reader = csv.reader(open('my_file.csv'))
ctr = 0
for record in my_reader:
    if record[1] == 'A':
        ctr += 1
print(ctr)
```

This is pretty fast, and I couldn't do better with the `Counter` method:

```
from collections import Counter
grades = [rec[1] for rec in my_reader] # generator expression was actually slower
result = Counter(grades)
print(result)
```

Last but not least, lists have a `count` method:

```
from collections import Counter
grades = [rec[1] for rec in my_reader]
result = grades.count('A')
print(result)
```